# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS not detecting external monitor anymore

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

It would be great if someone can help me. I was using the two external monitors plugged into ThinkPad-T14s-Gen-1 that has installed only Ubuntu 20.04, the laptop has AMD Ryzen 7 pro 4750u with radeon graphics.
One monitor was plugged into HDMI and other one into USB C socket, the laptop has two USB C sockets, one can be used both for charging and display, other one only for data.
Everything was working fine but, both of monitors were detected but after some updates, after I did some updates(apt get update and upgrade) from 20.04 to 20.04.1 and 20.04.02, one day it suddenly is not detecting the one monitor plugged into USB C socket, its not even working after unplugging and plugging it back in(before it would work if I unplug and plug it back)
The cable USB is good, its new and I have bought another one USB to check but they both dont work so its not about cables, it must be software issue. I am sharing my output of xrandr on terminal, btw I am absolute beginner to Linux. I have unplugged the monitor from HDMI, since its working but I plugged in the other one into USB C but its not detecting, its only detecting the laptop display(eDP):

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
1920x1080     60.00*+
1680x1050     60.00
1280x1024     60.00
1440x900      60.00
1280x800      60.00
1280x720      60.00
1024x768      60.00
800x600       60.00
640x480       60.00
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)